# opencv-python how to detect regions of interest in the same image and split them using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to detect ROI's in the same image using opencv with python. I can boundering the all image but I can't split the regions inside the image (the blocks of numbers) in two regions, for example.
My origin image is :

[image]

Actually, I have this following result:

[image: processed image]

I want to arrive in this following result:

[image]

My code:

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
plt.imshow(img)

#gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray)
#app threshold
th = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
plt.imshow(th)

x1,y1,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(th)
x2 = x1+w
y2 = y1+h

# Draw bounding rectangle
start = (x1, y1)
end = (x2, y2)
colour = (255, 0, 0)
thickness = 1
block_img = cv2.rectangle(img, start, end, colour, thickness)
plt.imshow(block_img)
```

How do I achieve this result? Do I must apply a contour or edge detection technique?. I would appreciate the help.
Tks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Threshold on red using cv2.inRange()
- Apply a horizontal rectangle closing morphology operation wide and tall enough to connect the letters and the rows, but not the two regions.
- Sort the contours largest first
- Loop over the top two contours and print and draw the bounding boxes on a copy of the input
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('number_chart.jpg')

# threshold on red letters
lower = (75,75,100)
upper = (150,150,160)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply horizontal morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (25,15))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get the two largest contours
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
#cntrs = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)
cntrs = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

# get bounding boxes of two largest contours and draw on copy of input
result = img.copy()
for i, cntr in enumerate(cntrs[0:2]):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    print(i, x, y, w, h)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("number_chart_boxes.png", result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Resulting Bounding Boxes:

[image]